# rails 3: layout for namespaced routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I've created a number of controllers & views under an 'admin' namespace, but they are still pulling from the application layout. how can I make a layout that applies to all the views in the namespaced routes, and still use the current layout for the other pages?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Generally speaking, Rails will use the application layout if there isn't a layout that matches the controller.  For example, if you had a PeopleController, Rails would look for layouts/people.html.erb and if it didn't find that, application.html.erb.

You can explicitly specify a specific layout if you want to override this convention.

```
class Admin::PeopleController
  layout 'some_layout'
end
```

That controller will then use some_layout.html.erb rather than looking for people.html.erb and application.html.erb.

**But this might be a better way if you're looking to group things:**  If you have a base AdminController that inherits from ApplicationController, you can have your, say, Admin::PersonController inherit from the AdminController and it will inherit the admin layout.

I don't know the specifics of your code, but you might have:

```
class AdminController
  def show
    #render a template linking to all the admin stuff
  end
end

app/controllers/admin/people_controller.rb:
class Admin::PeopleController < AdminController
  #your awesome restful actions in here!
end

views/layouts/admin.html.erb:
Hello from the Admin!
<%= yield %>
```

The one thing to realize is that Admin::PeopleController will inherit any actions that AdminController has defined (just as anything defined in ApplicationController becomes available in all sub-classes).  This isn't generally a problem since you'll likely be overwriting the methods anyway, but just to be aware of it.  If you don't have an AdminController, you can make one with no actions just for the purposes of the layout.

Comment: The `class AdminController` is under `app/controllers` or  `app/controllers/admin`?

Comment: under `app/controllers`

Comment: I'm trying this, and it seems to work, but I lose the styles and functionality given by frameworks like Bootstrap or Semantic-UI. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use the `AdminController` to render the main "index" page for all your admin stuff, because all the controllers that inherit from it are also going to inherit that `show` action. I think it's better make another separate controller that inherits from the `admin` controller, like `dashboard`, then have an `index` action in there instead.

Comment: @delba are you sure it isn't under `app/controllers/admin`? My Rails 4 project is setup this way, and it works with the latter.

Answer (score 45):

I usually have a Base controller class in my namespace, and then have all controllers in that namespace inherit from it. That allows me to put common, namespace specific code in Base and all the controllers in that namespace can take advantage. For example:

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
  before_filter :require_admin_user
end

class Admin::WidgetsController < Admin::BaseController
  # inherits the 'admin' layout and requires an admin user
end
```

Comment: I think this is more elegant and structured than the accepted answer. Is there any way to make all controllers generated by `rails g` command to inherit from `Admin::BaseController`?

Comment: where should this base controller go?

Comment: The controller class is Admin::BaseController, so Rails assumes it will be defined in the base_controller.rb file in the controllers/admin folder.

Comment: How can I create the layout file ***(html.erb)*** and only call for specific CSS and JS files which were created under **admin** folders in `stylesheets` and `javascripts` folders respectively?