# Providing a default layout for views within a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a series of controllers and associated views within my app that exist inside the `Admin` namespace. I want these views to use a different layout than those in the main namespace so I can give them a different appearance to the regular site. Is there a way I can do this using Rails' built in functionality? I know that if I have a `PostController` class and create a `posts.html.erb` view in the layouts directory this will be used as the layout for any of the controller's views, is there something similar I can do for namespaced controllers?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of, and definitely related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221856/rails-3-layout-for-namespaced-routes

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create custom AdminController class for your admin's controllers that you're going to inherit from. This AdminController inherits from ApplicationController and overrides layout.

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController   
  layout "admin" 
end

class Admin::PostController < AdminController 
end
```

Comment: Note that unlike *most* things in Rails, the layout name **must** be a `String`, not a `Symbol`. I.e. it must be `layout "admin"`, not `layout :admin`, which instead will yield an error like this: `NameError: Could not render layout: undefined local variable or method 'admin' for #<AdminController:0x00007ff135438bd0>`.

Answer (score 6):

There is not need in `layout` method. You should put your layout files for namespace into `views/layouts/<namespace>`.

Example namespace with name '`foo`':

Controller: `app/controllers/foo/bar_controller.rb`

Layout for this controller: `app/views/layouts/foo/bar.html.erb`

Comment: This would mean you have to create a layout for each namespaced view

Answer (score 5):

I believe you'll get the exact answer to your question in this beautiful screencast by Ryan Bates.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance

(i.e. if you're using Rails 3.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can override default layout for any controller with [layout](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods.html#method-i-layout) method