# Ruby route for custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

So I want when I access: site.com/panel to look into /app/controller/panel/index_controller.rb

Before I start I'm new to ruby, I started a couple hours ago

So in my routes.rb I have this

```
 namespace :panel do
   root 'index#index'
 resources :index
 end
```

And I created a file called index_controller.rb in /app/controller/panel/index_controller.rb which looks like this

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @foo = "Foo"
  end
end
```

Now when I go to site.com/panel I get this: superclass mismatch for class IndexController
[image]

What I did wrong? 
Also can I setup different views and layout here to use for the controllers inside /app/controller/panel/*_controller.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've namespaced the `index` resource routes within `panel`, you'll need to prefix your `IndexController` declaration to reflect this:

```
# app/controllers/index_controller.rb
class Panel::IndexController < ApplicationController
```

Then, you can similarly reflect the namespace in your filesystem in order to get Rails to properly invoke the correct views:

```
/app/views/panel/index/index.html.erb
/app/views/panel/index/show.html.erb
... etc
```

**A note**: the Rails convention is that routes that are declared as `resources` should be named *plural*, as this denotes an entirely resourceful class. Thus, according to this paradigm, `index` should actually be `indexes`. However, I suspect you may *mean* to use a ***singular*** route, in which case the declaration would be as follows:

```
namespace :panel do
    resource :index
end
```

Which creates the following singular routes (which may conform better to what you're trying to accomplish):

```
         panel_index POST   /panel/index(.:format)                         panel/indices#create
      new_panel_index GET    /panel/index/new(.:format)                     panel/indices#new
     edit_panel_index GET    /panel/index/edit(.:format)                    panel/indices#edit
                      GET    /panel/index(.:format)                         panel/indices#show
                      PUT    /panel/index(.:format)                         panel/indices#update
                      DELETE /panel/index(.:format)                         panel/indices#destroy
```

Comment: Such a great comment, the views work, but I guess I need to do a sort of checking in application_controller.rb in order to change to a different layout, something like: if site_url == /panel change layout to dis.html.erb

Comment: Right, but your question doesn't make any mention of this requirement. The question regarding namespace dependent layouts is distinct from what you've already asked, IMO. If this answer satisfies your question as it stands, would you kindly consider accepting it as correct?

Comment: Also can I setup different views and layout here to use for the controllers inside /app/controller/panel/*_controller.rb it's in the main question, I can accept it no problem, great answer but I thought you could also help me with the layout problem

Comment: I would __strongly__ recommend raising the issue in another question... the content of your questions is quickly becoming too dense, and your issue is more likely to attract quality solutions if you keep it succinct and to the point (again, IMO).

Comment: FYI, it may very well be easier and cleaner to declare a layout for each controller in the `panel` namespace. The logic required to implement a catch-all layout for a namespace is considerably more complex than that of merely adding a declaration for each controller. However, if you're inclined to pursue the catch-all approach, the following answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221856/rails-3-layout-for-namespaced-routes

Answer (score 2):

replace this

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
```

with

```
class Panel::IndexController < ApplicationController
```

update:

to automatically generate namespaced controller you can use rails build in generator like this

```
rails g controller panel/users
```

this will generate `Panel::Users < ApplicationController` controller under `app/controllers/panel/users_controller.rb`

Comment: This answer my first question, now how can I set another layout for this, thank you great answer

Comment: add a new layout into your layout folder..for example app/views/layouts/panel.html.erb .. specify the layout at the top of your controller with: layout "panel"

Comment: But I want to do it automatically, I don't want to do this manually for every controller in app/controller/panel/*_controller